# A term describing a majority that is bigger than 85% or 90%?

Tags: phrase-requests, terminology

Is there any term in English for describing a majority that is equal to or greater than 90% ?

Let's say out of 100 classmates 97 voted for John to be the class leader. What would be the right term to describe such a great percentage of those who voted for John?

Until today I thought that the correct term was "absolute majority", but having read the Wikipedia article just now, I realized that absolute majority is merely 50% of voters voting "in favor" plus one more "in favor" vote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One suitable and often-used phrase is **landslide majority**.

> 2. An overwhelming majority of votes for one party in an election.
>      *‘winning the election by a landslide’*
>      [as modifier] *‘a landslide victory’*
>
> [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/landslide)

Of course, *overwhelming* and its synonyms (as used by Oxford) will also be relevant.

The term *super-majority* is also heard, but that's different: that is the requirement for a greater majority than merely 50%+1 — for example, requiring a two-thirds majority or some even larger proportion.

Comment: However, this usage (as far as I know, and as mentioned in the quote) is only applied to the outcome of elections. It would not apply (again, as far as i know) to the passage of legislation or considerations of popular support. In this case, the "overwhelming majority" used in the quote would apply.

Comment: It's a good answer, except that the questioner seemed to have in mind a situation where the winner received 90%+ or maybe even 97% of the vote... whereas receiving a mere two-thirds of the vote could easily qualify as a landslide victory.  (Indeed, receiving 40% of the vote could be called a landslide victory if it resulted in a large majority in terms of seats.)

Comment: The problem is that the use of all these terms (*landslide, overwhelming, vast*) tends not to based on the percentages, but on comparing the actual result with what was expected. If, before the election, it seemed very uncertain whether a party would get 50% of the vote, then its getting 55% may be described as landslide. On the other hand, the same percentage is unlikely to be so described if everybody expected it.